# Iterator synchronization in parallel stream

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

If I create parallel stream from own Iterable like that:

```
StreamSupport.stream(new FilesToProcessIterable(customerId).spliterator(), true)
```

Must I care about state synchronization inside iterator implementation or it will be taken by Stream or Spliterator itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-)

> It is strongly recommended the spliterator report a characteristic of IMMUTABLE or CONCURRENT

So either you take an iterator, which is thread-safe, or you implement one but the method wont make it thread safe. You can use the supplier version as an alternative.

Comment: I've realised that I've chosen the wrong way to go :) I faced the classical producer-consumer problem but didn't realize that and started to invent something complex. But you answer seems to be correct in any way.